# Meteor (react) not rendering

Tags: javascript, reactjs, meteor

I tried following a course on Udemy, but I did my own tweaks on some of the coding, just to see if I could get it to work. 
But my code wont render in the localhost, so i am out here looking for help. Hopefully someone can look at the code and tell me why from looking at the below code:

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';

import ImageList from './components/imagelist';

export default class App extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <ImageList/>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

Meteor.startup(() => {
  ReactDOM.render(<App/>, document.getElementById('app'));
});

import React from 'react';

export default class ImageDetail extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <li className="media list-group-item">
        <div className="media-left">
          <img src={props.image.link}/>
        </div>
        <div className="media-body">
          <h4 className="media-heading">
            {props.image.title}
          </h4>
        </div>
      </li>
    );
  }
}

import React from 'react';

import ImageDetail from './imagedetails';

export default class ImageList extends React.Component {
  render() {
    const IMAGES = [
      {title: 'Pen', link: 'https://dummyimage.com/600x400'},
      {title: 'Pine tree', link: 'https://dummyimage.com/600x400'},
      {title: 'Mug', link: 'https://dummyimage.com/600x400'}
    ];

    RenderedImages = IMAGES.map(function(image) {
      return <ImageDetail image={image}/>
    });

    return (
      <ul className="media-list list-group">
        {this.RenderedImages}
      </ul>
    );
  }
}

<head>
  <title>Images</title>
</head>

<body>
  <div id="app"></div>
</body>
```

Comment: You must provide us with more than just "my code wont render". Provide us with an error, or a description of what's happening. It'd also be a good idea to break up your code into the different files you are using and describe their file location - Meteor has specific conventions in place that have implications on what code is run where.

Comment: What i mean by "not rendering" is, that it does not give me any errors, but i am just not able to see anything in the local host. Dont know, what else i can tell you.

Comment: So I'm assuming the page is blank (no elements are rendered). Does your browser console give you any warnings/errors? What about the meteor build tool?

Comment: In the Google Dev. it says, that the "DevTools failed to parse sourcemap"

Comment: In the `ImageDetail` you will need to use `this.props`, I believe

Answer (score 0):

if you are saying your code is not rendering as you expect it to. then you should know that in react , when you use map , you should provide a key for each item, thats how react keep track of it .  the key should be any unique property. in your case it can be title. usually it should be an id or you can use index . so at

```
  RenderedImages = IMAGES.map(function(image) {
      return <ImageDetail image={image}/>
    });
```

instead you should do this.

```
  RenderedImages = IMAGES.map(function(image) {
      return <ImageDetail key= {image.title} image={image}/>
    });
```

if it is not rendering at all , you should provide the error.

Answer (score 0):

What i mean by "not rendering" is, that it does not give me any errors, but i am just not able to see anything in the local host. Dont know, what else i can tell you.

Comment: Provide with the console log

Answer (score 0):

```
cd your/project/path
meteor npm install --save react react-dom
meteor add whatever-meteor-package
```

I had the same problem except I finally realized that imports from `meteor/some-lib` imply that I have to install via `meteor add some-lib` and others that don't begin with `meteor` in the import are to be install with `npm` or `meteor npm`. Such as `import { Component } from 'react';`

Then there's also relative local imports which don't need to be 'installed', but consider their possible dependencies.

This was really annoying to debug since I don't remember reading this in their tutorial and there's really no error messages for this. It just doesn't render like OP said.